# what language do i use to write a webpage in to automatically update from a database of sorts?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql

I have what I consider a bit of a tricky question. I am currently working on quite a large spread sheet (266 rows aith 70 coloumns and its only going to get bigger) that is a database of sorts and I want to remove it from Excel and put it on to an intranet page. I am currently writing it in a combination of HTML and Javascript for functionality, but it is becoming very hard to ensure that the data is in the right place. I am wondering if there is a possible way of being able to save the Excel spreadsheet into a certain format (like CSV or XML) and then write a program (for on a HTML page) that would display all of the infomation in a table automatically? is this even possible?

Unfortunatly i do not have access to a server to be able help with this, it all needs to be able to be coded in the page itself.

Thankyou for all your input Guys and Gals

Comment: 70 columns? As you are putting this data into a database, it sounds like you need to separate it out into multiple tables. There are few reasons a table should contain that many columns. You need to normalize your data.

Comment: The spread sheet that i am working with is a training matrix. it lists that workers names (1st cell of each row) with all of the current training offered across the top of the table. as the company is looking at adding further training in the future the table needs to be able expand to accommodate

Comment: Sounds like a nightmare you should just run away from. But if you have to, I would at the least try and get permission to deploy a proper web application first. At worst you could use a server side control to simply host the excel spreadsheet directly. At best you could use a small relational DB and some C# code to fill this baby out. 
With the restriction to do this all in the page, its looking kind of ugly no matter which direction you take.

Comment: that is exactly my point, you need to break that out into multiple tables. Without knowing more information it sounds like you need a "Employee", "Training", and "EmployeeTraining" tables.

Comment: what a nightmare this one has been. i've decided to do it the opld fashion way and creat the table in HTML and render the details into myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, a normalized database for this type of thing would look like this:

```
table `workers`
- id
- name
- ...

table `trainings`
- id
- title
- description
- ...

table `workers_in_training`
- worker_id
- training_id
```

This allows you to create a logical matrix as well without the need to change the schema (keep adding columns) for each new training/worker. Of course, this realistically requires a database server of some sort and knowledge in a server side programming language (PHP, Python, Ruby, C#, anything). If you don't have that, an Access database/app may be an acceptable compromise. Doing it all in Javascript is certainly interesting, but is an idea you should abandon as early as possible.

Comment: thanks for you comments on this questions. seeing as i do not have access to a server as such i have decided to abandon the idea of have some form of automation for this page and to just cretae the long and hard, but tried and semi reliable, way of creating a HTML table on my web page and hand filling it.

Answer (score 0):

Given your constraints, I would save the Excel spreadsheet as a CSV and put it in the same location as your HTML file, then use AJAX to fetch the contents of the CSV and dynamically generate a HTML table based on the contents.

Look here for how to fetch a URL's contents using AJAX (jQuery library): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

After fetching the URL content, you will have the CSV as a big string in a JavaScript variable.  I'll let you have the fun of figuring out how to parse it :-)

Once you know how to parse your CSV string to recognise rows and columns, look here for how to generate HTML table dynamically using jQuery library: [Building an HTML table on the fly using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103489/building-an-html-table-on-the-fly-using-jquery)

Comment: The real problem comes when you try to persist any changes though.

Comment: I assumed he wanted to just render the contents and not edit it.  What a hopeless situation if the client JavaScript has to change the spreadsheet contents!

Comment: Yoshi, right you are, i was wanting to render the contents. the client side of this projct is to be a read only Intranet page that only i have access to the info to change. i was not looking for the Javascript to change the spreadsheet contents.