# Dynamic table from user input with cell id as grid reference

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am trying to create a table that is generated by user input data.

The table is reflecting a grid therfore I want the id of each cell to be the co ordinate of that grid. So the id of the bottom left cell would be id00. The top right cell id would be the maximum size of the grid that the user has entered.

So for example if data entered; x value=3;  y value=3
this would produce the following table:

```
<table>
<tr><td id="id03"></td><td id="id13"></td><td id="id23"></td><td id="id33"></td></tr>
<tr><td id="id02"></td><td id="id12"></td><td id="id22"></td><td id="id32"></td></tr>    
<tr><td id="id01"></td><td id="id11"></td><td id="id21"></td><td id="id31"></td></tr>
<tr><td id="id00"></td><td id="id10"></td><td id="id20"></td><td id="id30"></td></tr>
</table>
```

I have identified the basic concept for the code as you can see below:

```
<table>
Create a loop,  initial value of r= 0; maximum value of r=y
r =0 <tr> create a secondary  loop, initial value of n=0; maximum value of n = x;  r remains  constant for row
n=0; r= 0 <td  id = “id” + “[x- (x-n)]” +   “[y-r]” > </td>
….
n=3; r= 0* <td id = “id” + “[x- (x-n)]” +   “[y-r]” > </td>
</tr>

….

r =3 <tr> n=0; r= 3 <td  id = “id” + “[x- (x-n)]” +   “[y-r]” > </td>
….
n=3; r= 3<td id = “id” + “[x- (x-n)]” +   “[y-r]” > </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to develop it in Javascript but I am new to the language and I am having trouble coding it.

Any help anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103489/building-an-html-table-on-the-fly-using-jquery

Comment: Have you tried my answer ? any comments ? votes ? accept it ?

Comment: Hi ManseUK, thank you for your response. I havent had a chance to try it out yet (I'm suppose to be working) but I've had a quick look at the JSfiddle and I can see two issues, first is that the id should be read as a grid co ordinates. You have x and y the wrong way round - although i dont imagine this will be two hard to fix?  The second issue which may be more complicated is: If a user enters a value of 3 for the columns (x value) I want there to be 4 columns as 0 also has a column (0,1,2,3). Similariy if a user enters a value of 0 there is 1 column. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
var rows = parseInt(document.getElementById('rows').value,10); // get input value
var cols = parseInt(document.getElementById('cols').value,10); // get input value
var table = document.createElement('table'); // create table element
table.border = "1"; // set some attributes
var prevrow; // used to store previous row element
for (var r = 0; r < (rows+1); r++) {  // loop rows
    var row = document.createElement('tr'); // create tr
    for (var c = 0; c < (cols+1); c++) { // loop cols
        var col = document.createElement('td'); // create td
        col.id = 'id' + r + c;  // set id of tr
        col.innerHTML = col.id; // add some text
        row.appendChild(col); // append td to tr
    }
    // if first tr then create append to table else insert before previous tr
    if (prevrow) {
        table.insertBefore(row, prevrow);
    } else {
        table.appendChild(row);
    }
    // store newly create tr
    prevrow = row;
}
// append the new table to the output div
document.getElementById('output').appendChild(table);
```

Uses [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement), [`element.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.appendChild) and [`element.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.insertBefore) to build the table

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/g9ZMf/22/)

Comment: Hi ManseUK, Thank you for your response, It seems to be working well apart from one issues that I am unable to work out: The table is representing a grid, therfroe if a user enters a value of 3 for the columns (x value) I want there to be 4 columns as 0 also has a column (0,1,2,3). Similariy if a user enters a value of 3 for the rows (y value) then there are 4 rows. If a user was to enter 0 for both input fields then there would be 1 cell. If you could help with this last issue it would be most appreciated, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var x = 3; // value from input
var y = 4; // value from input

var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
for(var i = 0; i < y; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    for(var j = 0; j < x; j++) {
        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.id = "id" + (j) + (y - i - 1);
        cell.innerHTML = cell.id;        
    }
}
​
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/6YKcK/)

Comment: +1 nice example - I added the code to your answer - its a lot better to add the code and include a link to the jsfiddle instead of just the link