# Selectable rows in a table generated with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've already searched the site for answers, but I couldn't adapt the code provided for other people to mine.

I have a table generated by PHP using mysql queries, I'd like to make the rows selectable (the whole rows only, and no multi-selection) and extract the value of "CodPezzi" from the selected row for further usage:

This is my table

```
<table width="504" border="1" align="center" class="Tabella" id="maintable">
    <th>Codice</th>
    <th>Tipologia</th>
    <th>Costruttore</th>
    <th>Macchinario</th>
    <th>Quantità</th>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $result=$ SSide->query($sql); 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
            echo " <tr <td>".$row['CodPezzi']."</td>". "
                <td>".$row['Tipologia']."</td>". "
                <td>".$row['Macchinario']."</td>". "
                <td>".$row['Costruttore']."</td>". "
                <td>".$row['sum(Quantita)']."</td>
           </tr>";
        }    
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I don't want to have the header selectable. Can you provide me a slim code that allows me to do what I want to do?

## Edit

This is what I tried before coming here:

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <style>
         #selectable-1 .ui-selecting { background: #707070 ; }
         #selectable-1 .ui-selected { background: #EEEEEE; color: #000000; }
         #selectable-1 { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; 
            padding: 0; width: 20%; }
         #selectable-1 li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; 
            font-size: 16px; height: 18px; }
         .ui-widget-content {
            background: #cedc98;
            border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
            color: #333333;
         }
      </style>
      <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#selectable-1" ).selectable();
         });
      </script>
   </head>
    <body>
        <table width="504" border="1" align="center" class="Tabella"id="selectable-1" >
            <th >Codice</th> 
            <th >Tipologia</th>
            <th >Costruttore</th>
            <th >Macchinario</th>
            <th >Quantità</th>
            <tbody>
                <?php 
                $result = $SSide->query($sql);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result)){
                    echo "<tr> <li <td>".$row['CodPezzi']."</td> </li>".
                        "<li class="ui-widget-content"><td>".$row['Tipologia']."</td> ".
                        "<li class="ui-widget-content"><td>".$row['Macchinario']."</td></li>".
                        "<li class="ui-widget-content"><td>".$row['Costruttore']."</td></li>".
                        "<li class="ui-widget-content"><td>".$row['sum(Quantita)']."</td></li>
                    </tr>";
                }?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

and also

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <style>
        #maintable {
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        #maintable tr:hover {
          background-color: #FFFFAA;
        }
        #maintable tr.selected td {
          background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFCF8B;
          color: #000000;
        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <table width="504" border="1" align="center" class="Tabella" id="maintable">
        <th>Codice</th>
        <th>Tipologia</th>
        <th>Costruttore</th>
        <th>Macchinario</th>
        <th>Quantità</th>
        <tbody>

          <?php $result=$ SSide->query($sql); while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result)){ echo "
          <tr>
            <td>".$row['CodPezzi']."</td>". "
            <td>".$row['Tipologia']."</td>". "
            <td>".$row['Macchinario']."</td>". "
            <td>".$row['Costruttore']."</td>". "
            <td>".$row['sum(Quantita)']."</td>
          </tr>"; }?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script language="javascript">
        <!--
         //<![CDATA[
        $("#maintable tr").click(function() {
          //alert($(this).hasClass("selected"));
          if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
          } else {
            $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
          }
        });
         //]]>
         -->
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The rows become highlightable on mouse over, but not selectable.

Comment: Fix your HTML and show us what you´ve tried.

Comment: Stand back! This sounds like a job for JavaScript! SO is not a place where folks will just provide code without you showing some effort. Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: @JayBlanchard At least 500 feet. *Mornin' Sam!*

Comment: *Mornin' Ralph!* Yep @Fred-ii-, maybe even a thousand! ;-)

Comment: *Wile E. holding up YIPES! sign* @JayBlanchard

Comment: Exactly! @Fred-ii- `<insert whistling dropping sound effect here>`

Comment: ............... *POOF!* @JayBlanchard ouch.

Comment: Actually LOL'ing here @Fred-ii- as *that* is exactly what I was thinking!

Comment: Your server (PHP) should return JSON. The client (JavaScript) should build the tables and populate said tables with the JSON data. Check out a JavaScript plugin to build the tables for you. Here is one: [*DynaTable*](http://www.dynatable.com/). I recommend you read this answer if you want to do it yourself. [*Stackoverflow: Building an HTML table on the fly using jQuery*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/106624/1762224). [*JSRender*](https://github.com/borismoore/jsrender) is a powerful jQuery templating engine that is the spawn of the original *jquery-tmpl* plugin.

Comment: It's a very complete plug-in and i will definitely look into it, but at the moment i feel to be closer to the solution by using the jquery ui selectable (as seen in other articles).

Comment: You have a lot of invalid html, for instance "`<tr <td>`" and your tables are missing their `<thead>` tag; you need to place your `<th>` elements inside  it.

Comment: invalid html is due to copy-paste: you asked for previous tries and i replicated them in the post, not on my source code (since they're messy). I'm sorry if something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StackOverflow is not a place to ask people to write code for you, but I can point you towards a solution:

When you create your table rows

```
echo "<tr>
   <td>".$row['CodPezzi']."</td>". "
   <td>".$row['Tipologia']."</td>". "
   ...";
```

You can include ids and classes like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result)){
echo "<tr class='selectableRow'>
   <td class='CodPezzi'>".$row['CodPezzi']."</td>". "
   <td>".$row['Tipologia']."</td>". "
   ...";
```

Then you catch the relevant events in jquery:

```
$("tr.selectableRow").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).css("background","blue");
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).css("background","");
  }
);

$("tr.selectableRow").click(function () {
       //
    );
```

This should help you get on the right track.